# Applying ARCH LM test on data

Tags: arch

my question is related to ARCH LM test. Actually I have quarterly CPI data for Pakistan with base 2005. I have converted it into Y-O-Y growth rate by taking log difference and then made it stationary. when I apply ARCH LM test on raw data it shows significant results but when I apply it on differenced data, this test becomes insignificant. I want to ask on which type of data we should apply ARCH LM test